# Content type is different from properties when sending out with MessageChannel (get from BinderAwareChannelResolver)

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I have the following codes:

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class AMQPService {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private BinderAwareChannelResolver binderAwareChannelResolver;

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void processMessage(@Payload Map<String, Object> inboundMessage, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        headers.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + '=' + e.getValue()));

        String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(inboundMessage);
        AMQPOutboundMessage outMessage = new AMQPOutboundMessage();
        outMessage.setText(output);
        if (headers.containsKey("expected_destination")) {
            MessageChannel messageChannel = binderAwareChannelResolver.resolveDestination(headers.get("expected_destination").toString());
            messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(outMessage).setHeader("contentType", "application/json;charset=UTF-8").build());
    }
}
```

}

It just gets amqp message from RabbitMQ and then just according to the "expected_destination" header to sends the message to the destination.

I've set `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json;charset=UTF-8`, but I saw the content-type of the message is `application/x-java-object;type=xxx.AMQPOutboundMessage` and base64 encoded message body.

But when I use `@Autowired` to get messageChannel, it seems everything is fine.

So, may I know how to set the content-type in this case please?

Answer (score 0):

The setting `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json;charset=UTF-8` will only apply to the channel named `output`, not to all output channels.

In this version, you will need to have a configuration for each expected output, i.e. the possible values of `expected_destination`. We are considering supporting default settings in the future, i.e. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/446

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But the question is it is hard to list all the potential values of `expected_destination` in my case. Or, is there any method to set the `content-type` with code?